# Openstack authenticate with python SDK v2

Tags: python, rest, openstack, devstack

I am a OpenStack noob here.

I try to use `REST API` to automate my `openstack` work. I can **successfully** authenticate my account and get token from `curl` with below command:

```
export AUTH_URL="https://my_url:5000/v2.0/tokens"
curl -v -X POST $AUTH_URL -d '{"auth":{"passwordCredentials":{"username": "myusername", "password":"myuser_password"}, "tenantId":"my_tenant_id"}}' -H 'Content-type: application/json' | python -m json.tool
```

But, when I try to use `Pyton`, with this code, it gave me this **error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 10, in <module>
    keystone = ksclient.Client(auth_url=auth_url, username=user_name, password=user_pwd, tenant_name=tenant_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneclient/v2_0/client.py", line 176, in __init__
    self.authenticate()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/positional/__init__.py", line 101, in inner
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneclient/httpclient.py", line 581, in authenticate
    resp = self.get_raw_token_from_identity_service(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keystoneclient/v2_0/client.py", line 220, in get_raw_token_from_identity_service
    _("Authorization Failed: %s") % e)
keystoneauth1.exceptions.auth.AuthorizationFailure: Authorization Failed: The resource could not be found. (HTTP 404) (Request-ID:
```

My python code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import keystoneclient.v2_0.client as ksclient

auth_url  = "https://my_url:5000/v2.0/tokens"
user_name = "myusername"
user_pwd  = "myuser_password"
tenant_name = "my_tenant_id"

keystone = ksclient.Client(auth_url=auth_url, username=user_name, password=user_pwd, tenant_name=tenant_name)

print keystone.auth_token
```

Can you please take a look at my code and see why the python code does not work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should only provide `https://my_url:5000/v2.0` as the path when authenticating using the client.

See [this](https://docs.openstack.org/python-keystoneclient/latest/using-api-v2.html) documentation for more information.

You could also try something like this.

```
from keystoneauth1 import loading
from keystoneauth1 import session
from keystoneclient import client as keystoneclient

auth_url = 'https://my_url:5000'
user = '<user>'
password = '<password>'
tenant = '<tenant>'

loader = loading.get_plugin_loader('password')

keystone_auth = \
    loader.load_from_options(
        auth_url=auth_url,
        username=user,
        password=password,
        user_domain_name=tenant
    )

keystone_session = session.Session(
    auth=keystone_auth,
    verify=False
)

print(keystone_session.get_token())
```

Keep in mind that the Keystone V2 API has been deprecated, and removed in the latest versions of Openstack. If possible I would recommend moving over to the V3 API as soon as possible.

Comment: I met the same issue. I have the same URL as you mentioned. But it returns me HTTP 401 error (The request you have made requires authentication). I am sure that the username/password are correct as I can authenticate with curl commands. Please help! Thank you! I have the piece of code copied from here: https://docs.openstack.org/python-keystoneclient/latest/using-api-v2.html (with changed my username/password, url, and tenant)

Comment: What version of Openstack are you running? also what version of the keystoneclient?

Comment: Make sure to use an older version of the keystoneclient, as v2 is no longer supported.